# Need help with surface area and volume of "cheese slice"

Tags: geometry

If you had a cheese slice that was like a that was like a segment of a cylinder how can you calculate the volume and surface area?

The height of the cheese slice is 16 cm, the length is 4cm and the angle of the cheese slice is 25 degrees.
How could you calculate the surface area and volume?
Please show working out.

> [image: The Cheese slice]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: is the outer edge circular or straight if it is circular is it the same radius?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am assuming the cheese slice is cut out from a disk of radius $4 \text{ cm}$ and the slice retains its shape.

From the top, the slice would look like a sector of a circle.

**Surface Area**

Its arc-length $\, l \,$ would be

$$\begin{align*}
l \, &= \, 2 \pi r \cdot \frac{\theta}{360} \\[0.3cm]
&= \, 2 \pi \cdot 4 \cdot  \frac{25}{360} \\[0.3cm]
&= \, 1.745 \text{ cm}
\end{align*}$$

[$\theta \,$ is the central angle in degrees]

That means the perimeter of the sector is

$$\begin{align*}
P \, &= \, l + 2r \\[0.3cm]
&= \, 1.745 + 2 \cdot 4 \\[0.3cm]
&= \, 9.745 \text{ cm}^2
\end{align*}$$

Since the cross-section of the slice is uniform, we can get its lateral surface area ($A_1$) by multiplying together the perimeter of the sector and the slice's height. So,

$$\begin{align*}
A_1 \, &= \, P \times h \\[0.3cm]
&= \, 9.745 \times 16 \\[0.3cm]
&= \, 155.92 \text{ cm}^2
\end{align*}$$

To get the total surface area (A), we need to add the area of the top and bottom surfaces (each being the sector mentioned above).

Now, area of the sector ($A_2$) is

$$\begin{align*}
l \, &= \, \pi r^2 \cdot \frac{\theta}{360} \\[0.3cm]
&= \, \pi \cdot 4^2 \cdot  \frac{25}{360} \\[0.3cm]
&= \, 3.49 \text{ cm}^2
\end{align*}$$

So,

$$\begin{align*}
A \, &= \, A_1 + 2A_2 \\[0.3cm]
&= \, 155.92 + 2 \cdot 3.49 \\[0.3cm]
&= \, 162.9 \text{ cm}^2
\end{align*}$$

**Volume**

Again, because of the uniform cross-section, we can get the volume by multiplying the area of the sector ($A_2$ calculated above) by the slice's height.

$$\begin{align*}
V \, &= \, A_2 \cdot h \\[0.3cm]
&= \, 3.49 \cdot 16 \\[0.3cm]
&= \, 55.84 \text{ cm}^3
\end{align*}$$